# Do constexpr values cause binary size to increase?

Tags: c++, templates, constexpr

I know that templatized types such as the below cost nothing on the compiled binary size:

```
template<auto value>
struct ValueHolder{};
```

I'm making a program that will use a LOT of such wrapped types, and I don't think I want to be using `integral_constant`s for that reason, since they have a `::value` member.  I can get away with something more like:

```
template<typename ValHolder>
struct Deducer;

template<auto value>
struct Deducer<ValueHolder<value>> {
    using Output = ValueHolder<value+1>;
};
```

But it's definitely a bit more work, so I want to make sure I'm not doing it for nothing.  Note that we're talking TONS of such values (I'd explain, but I don't want to go on too far a tangent; I'd probably get more comments about "should I do the project" than the question!).

So the question is: Do [static] constexpr values take any size at all in the compiled binary, or are the values substituted at compile-time, as if they were typed-in literally?  I'm pretty sure they DO take size in the binary, but I'm not positive.

I did a little test at `godbolt` to look at the assembly of a constexpr vs non-constexpr array side-by-side, and everything looked pretty similar to me: https://godbolt.org/z/9hecfq

```
int main()
{
    // Non-constexpr large array
    size_t arr[0xFFFF] = {};

    // Constexpr large array
    constexpr size_t cArr[0xFFF] = {};

    // Just to avoid unused variable optimizations / warnings
    cout << arr[0] << cArr[0] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This depends entirely on:

1. How much the compiler feels like optimizing the variable away.
2. How you *use* the variable.

Consider the code you posted. You created a `constexpr` array. As this is an array, it is 100% legal to index it with a runtime value. This would require the compiler to emit code that accesses the array at that index, which would require that array to actually *exist* in memory. So if you use it in such a way, it *must* have storage.

However, since your code only indexes this array with a constant expression index, a compiler that wants to think a bit more than `-O0` would allow would realize that it knows the value of all of the elements in that array. So it knows exactly what `cArr[0]` is. And that means the compiler can just convert that expression into the proper value and just ignore that `cArr` exists.

Such a compiler could do the same with `arr`, BTW; it doesn't have to be a constant expression for the compiler to detect a no-op.

Also, note that since both arrays are non-static, neither will take up storage "in the compiled binary". If runtime storage for them is needed, it will be stack space, not executable space.

Broadly speaking, a `constexpr` variable will take up storage at any reasonable optimization level if you do something that *requires* it to take up storage. This could be something as innocuous as passing it to a (un-inlined) function that takes the parameter by `const&`.

Comment: Thanks, in my actual use-case, the variables generally are static, but I am trying to not "count on" compiler optimizations.  So I will go through the trouble of using deduction around wrapped values, I think.  Glad I now don't have it in the back of my head that "this might be for nothing"! ;-)

Comment: @Sean: "*I am trying to not "count on" compiler optimizations*" Then why are you writing C++ code? Performance in pretty much any C++ of significance is going to rely heavily on the compiler doing reasonable things with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Ask your linker :) There is nothing anywhere in the C++ standard that has any bearing on the answer. So you absolutely, positively, must build your code in release mode, and check if *in the particular use scenario* it does increase the size or not.

**Any general results you obtain on other platforms, different compilers (1), other compile options, other modules added/removed to your project, or even any changes to the code, will not have much relevance.**

You have a *specific* question that depends on so many factors that general answers are IMHO useless.

But moreover, if you *actually care* about the binary size, then it should be already in your test/benchmark suite, you should have integration builds fail when things grow when they shouldn’t, etc. No measurement and no automation are *prima facie evidence that you don’t actually care*.

So, since you presumably do care about the binary size, just write the code you had in mind and look in your CI dashboard at the binary size metric. Oh, you don’t have it? Well, that’s the first thing to get done before you go any further. I’m serious.

(1): Same compiler = same binary. I’m crazy, you say? No. It bit me once too many. If the compiler binary is different (other than time stamps), it’s not the same compiler, end of story.